# How can I pass variables from an isolated scope directive to a child?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two isolated scope directives. Ideally I like both to work independently and not require any custom templates. The first directive is going to be page scroll watcher, when it hits a certain point I want it to trigger an update in the other directive. Is it possible for a child directive to watch a variable in the parent directive?

I've created a simple plunkr to illustrate the issue, http://plnkr.co/edit/wwfBzmemyrj1r1R54riM?p=preview

```
    /*
 <div ng-outer>Outer directive {{myvar}}
      <div ng-inner="myvar">Inner directive</div>
    </div>
    */
app.directive('ngOuter', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A'
        ,scope:{}
    }
    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function(){
          scope.myvar = "test 001"
        },1000)
    }
    return directive;

}]);

app.directive('ngInner', [ function () {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A'
        ,scope:{ data: '=ngInner',  myvar: '=myvar' }
    }
    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal){
          if(newVal)
          element.text("new inner val", newVal);
        });
          scope.$watch('myvar', function(newVal, oldVal){
          if(newVal)
          element.text("new myvar", newVal);
        });


    }

    return directive;

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by using

```
angular.element(element.parent()).isolateScope();
```

The child directive can access the scope of the parent directive and watch variables etc.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RAO6q81ZE4tClMDMiLFb?p=preview

Comment: Normally it is not a good practice to access the oarent scope . You can use $scope.$parent also.

Comment: Though this is true, if you are doing it that way, you are doing some things wrong. As child scopes prototypally inherit from parent scope, you do not need to this. It would be messy when the code grows and you will find yourself writing $parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.help()

Comment: a shared service is not going to work if you have multiple instances of the directive on the same page

Comment: If you set and get the sharedValue in order the value will be synchronized. Also Javascript is a SingleThreaded language.

Answer (score 0):

First approach of passing variable from parent directive to the child is by using an 'attr' in child scope with '@' and initialize it in parent controller as following:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('ngOuter', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return{
       restrict: 'E',
       scope:{},
       template: '<ng-inner attr="{{myvar}}">Inner directive {{myvar}}</ng-inner>',
       controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.myvar = "test 001";
       }],
       link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

       }
    }
}]);

app.directive('ngInner', [ function () {
    return{
       restrict: 'E',
       scope:{'attr' : "@"},
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(scope.attr);
       } 
    }
}]);
```

html:

```
    <ng-outer></ng-outer>
```

2nd approach is utilizing a function in a parent controller which returns the "myvar" value and call that function in child directive:

```
app.directive('ngOuter', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{},
        template: '<ng-inner attr="{{myvar}}">Inner directive {{myvar}}</ng-inner>',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.myvar = "test 001";
            this.getMyvar = function() {
                return $scope.myvar;
            };
        }],
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

       }
   }

}]);

app.directive('ngInner', [ function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^ngOuter',
        scope:{'attr' : "@"},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentDirCtrl) {
            console.log(parentDirCtrl.getMyvar());
        } 
    }

}]);
```

3rd Approach: you can inject a service to both inner and outer directives.Then use the service.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.service('myService', [
  function() {
    var service = {
      myvar: 'test001',
      setMyVar: function(value) {
        this.myvar = value;
      },
      getMyVar: function() {
        return this.myvar;
      }
    }
    return service;
  }
]);



app.directive('ngOuter', ['$timeout', 'myService',
  function($timeout, myService) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {}
    }
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        scope.myvar = myService.getMyVar();
      }, 1000)
    }
    return directive;

  }
]);

app.directive('ngInner', ['myService',
  function(myService) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {}
    }
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var variable = myService.getMyVar();
      console.log("myvar", variable);
    }
    return directive;

  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked at the 2nd approach. A couple of issues. http://plnkr.co/edit/TFWtf20hKSKnEaKZbZIb?p=preview The first is it doesn't seem to work without using a template. The second issue adding require to the inner directive creates a dependency on the outer. I'd like the option to use the inner directive without the outer too.

Comment: I managed to get it working by exposing the parent scope via the controller. I can then watch a variable from the child directive. However I still need to use require, so the the child directive with only function if wrapped by the parent. Ideally I want the parent directive to be optional. Is there another approach I can take? http://plnkr.co/edit/VcTgMm7zu78XE681d17w?p=preview

Comment: Although this is true, if you are doing it that way, you are doing some things wrong. As child scopes prototypally inherit from parent scope, you do not need to this. It would be messy when the code grows and you will find yourself writing $parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.help(). You need to make an API controller an pass it to the directive scope as "^apiCtrl"

Comment: 3rd Approach: you can inject a service to both inner and outer directives.Then use the service.